# The filter no longer works when I clear the input value

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is an idea of the HTML table with an input that will filter the plans.

[image]

I enter for example the value => `1`

The filter works

[image]

I delete the value (1)

all recordings are displayed, **I have 4 recordings**

[image]

I try the value `4`

[image]

I delete the value `4`

I have 2 recordings ????

[image]

I don't understand the problem ?

**todo.component.ts**

```
filterByPlan() {
    if (this.planFilter) {
      this.tarificationTitre = this.todoService.PLN_PLC.filter((item) => {
        return item.PLN_SVM.some((svm) => {
          return svm.PLN.some(
            (plan) => plan.PLAN === parseInt(this.planFilter)
          );
        });
      }).map((item) => {
        item.PLN_SVM = item.PLN_SVM.filter((svm) => {
          return svm.PLN.some(
            (plan) => plan.PLAN === parseInt(this.planFilter)
          );
        });
        return item;
      });
    } else {
      this.tarificationTitre = this.todoService.PLN_PLC;
    }
  }
```

**todo.service.ts**

```
export class TodoService {

   PLN_PLC = [
      {
        PLACECODE: 26,
        PLACELABEL: "Fundsettle",
        PLN_SVM: [
          {
            SVM: 16111801,
            ISIN: "LU0100749679",
            LABEL: "NEKR FD LIFESTYLE DYNAMICC",
            PLN: [
              {
                CODE: "NEKR01",
                PLAN: 8,
                CANAL: "*",
                AV: "A",
                LIB: "Fonds NEKRenta 8",
                DATEV_EFFECTIVE: "0001-01-01",
                PLAGE: [
                  {
                    BORNE: 9999999999999.99,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE: 1,
                    COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 1,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 2.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                  },
                  {
                    BORNE: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE: 0,
                    COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                  },
                  {
                    BORNE: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE: 0,
                    COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                  },
                  {
                    BORNE: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE: 0,
                    COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                  },
                  {
                    BORNE: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE: 0,
                    COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 0,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                  }
                ]
              },
            
            ]
          },
         
         {
            SVM:37906990,
            ISIN:"FR0010149302",
            LABEL:"CARMIGNAC EMERGENT SC",
            PLN:[
               {
                  CODE:"NEKR01",
                  PLAN:8,
                  CANAL:"*",
                  AV:"A",
                  LIB:"Fonds NEKRenta 8",
                  DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
                  PLAGE:[
                     {
                        BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:2.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     },
                     {
                        BORNE:0.00,
                        FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                        FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                        TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                        COURTAGE:0.00,
                        MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                        TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                        FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                        MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                     }
                  ]
               },
               
            ]
         },
         {
          SVM:135045622,
          ISIN:"FR0010149120",
          LABEL:"CARMIGNAC SECURITE C",
          PLN:[
             {
                CODE:"NEKR01",
                PLAN:4,
                CANAL:"*",
                AV:"A",
                LIB:"Fonds NEKRenta 4",
                DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
                PLAGE:[
                   {
                      BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:1.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                CODE:"NEKR01",
                PLAN:4,
                CANAL:"*",
                AV:"V",
                LIB:"Fonds NEKRenta 4",
                DATEV_EFFECTIVE:"0001-01-01",
                PLAGE:[
                   {
                      BORNE:9999999999999.99,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:1,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:1,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   },
                   {
                      BORNE:0.00,
                      FRAIS_BORDEREAU:0.00,
                      FRAIS_RETRAIT:0.00,
                      TYPE_COURTAGE:0,
                      COURTAGE:0.00,
                      MIN_COURTAGE:0.00,
                      TYPE_FRAIS_ETR:0,
                      FRAIS_ETRANGERS:0.00,
                      MIN_FRAIS_ETR:0.00
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       },
         
        ]
      },
      {
        PLACECODE: 1,
        PLACELABEL: "Euronext Brussels",
        PLN_SVM: [
          {
            SVM: 836129993,
            ISIN: "BE0974314461",
            LABEL: "BALTA GROUP",
            PLN: [
              {
                CODE: "NEKR01",
                PLAN: 1,
                CANAL: "*",
                AV: "A",
                LIB: "Fonds NEKRenta 1",
                DATEV_EFFECTIVE: "0001-01-01",
                PLAGE: [
                  {
                    BORNE: 9999999999999.99,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE: 1,
                    COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 1,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.25,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                CODE: "NEKR01",
                PLAN: 1,
                CANAL: "*",
                AV: "V",
                LIB: "Fonds NEKRenta 1",
                DATEV_EFFECTIVE: "0001-01-01",
                PLAGE: [
                  {
                    BORNE: 9999999999999.99,
                    FRAIS_BORDEREAU: 0.00,
                    FRAIS_RETRAIT: 0.00,
                    TYPE_COURTAGE: 1,
                    COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    MIN_COURTAGE: 0.00,
                    TYPE_FRAIS_ETR: 1,
                    FRAIS_ETRANGERS: 0.00,
                    MIN_FRAIS_ETR: 0.00
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

  constructor() {}
  
}
```

The filter must filter on the variable `PLAN`

If you have an idea, I'm really interested, because I really want to understand where the problem is.

I also made an illustration on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zus4xd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodo%2Ftodo.service.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one it will work

```
  filterByPlan() {
if (this.planFilter) {
  this.tarificationTitre = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( this.todoService.PLN_PLC)).filter((item:any) => {
    return item.PLN_SVM.some((svm:any) => {
      return svm.PLN.some(
        (plan:any) => plan.PLAN === parseInt(this.planFilter)
      );
    });
  }).map((item:any) => {
    item.PLN_SVM = item.PLN_SVM.filter((svm:any) => {
      return svm.PLN.some(
        (plan:any) => plan.PLAN === parseInt(this.planFilter)
      );
    });
    return item;
  });
} else {
  this.tarificationTitre = this.todoService.PLN_PLC;
}
```

}

I just do some deep copy for now
you are accessing main array data(which stored in todo service) directly which
making some changes in that array and it reflcting wrong data.

Hope this will work

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was stuck for 3 days. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Within `filterByPlan()`, I think you are overwriting the `PLN_SVM` objects of each location defined within the service with the values which match the current filter.